# Show that if a is a QR mod p and q then a is a QR mod pq

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ and $q$ be two different prime numbers and $a∈ \Bbb{Z}$ be an integer number such that $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo both $p$ and $q$. Prove that there exists $x∈ \Bbb{Z}$ such that $a≡x^2$ (mod pq).

I'm envisioning a CRT style argument with letting $a=y^2$ (mod p) and $a=z^2$ (mod q) but can't quite make it work.

Edit:

Using the CRT I have let $1 = pr + qs$ and then shown that $x = ypr + zps$ which satisfies both $x≡y$ (mod p) and $x≡z$ (mod q).

I have then tried to show that $x^2≡a$ (mod pq) but haven't got anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chinese Remainder theorem is the way to go. If $y^2\equiv a\pmod p$
and $z^2\equiv a\pmod q$, then by CRT there is $x$ with $x\equiv y\pmod p$
and $x\equiv z\pmod q$. You should be able to show that $x^2\equiv a\pmod{pq}$.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to how to answer the question fully, I have edited it to show where I am currently

Comment: You have $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ and $x^2\equiv a\pmod q$.

Comment: The CRT says that, if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, then the mapping $f:\mathbb Z_{pq} \to \mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_q$ defined by $f(\bar x) = (\bar x, \bar x)$ is an isomorphism. Let $\bar x = f^{-1}(\bar y, \bar z)$. Then $f(\bar x^2) = (f(\bar x))^2 = (\bar y, \bar z)^2 = (\bar y^2, \bar z^2) = (\bar a, \bar a) = f(\bar a)$. Hence $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{pq}$